# how to get client address in a multithreading TCP server for each connection

Tags: c, multithreading, network-programming

in a multithreading tcp server, I don't know how to store the client address for each cocnnection.

First, let's consider the case where in each thread, there is only 1 tcp connection(namely only one connfd) at the same time.This client address will be used in each thread.

for multh-threading tcp server, there are three types:

(1) one thread per connection, in this type, I can use thread-specific data to store the client address. Like:

```
listen(listenfd, backlog);
pthread_key_create(&key, null);
for(;;){
    connfd=accept(listenfd, client_addr, socklen);
    pthread_create(pid, null, func, null);
    ..
 }
```

and

```
func(){
  pthread_setspecific(key,(void *)client_addr);
  // **and then the client_addr can be obtained by pthread_getspecific(key)**
}
```

are there any problem in this solution?
I'm afraid that before  `pthread_setspecific()` is called, `accept()` is called again and client_addr is changed.

(2) Half-syn and half-async: this is similar to (1)

(3) leader-follower type:

```
 connfd=listen(listenfd, backlog);
 pthread_key_create(&key, null);
 for(i:N){
     pthread_create(pid, null, func, null);
 }

 func(){
      accept(listenfd, client_addr, socklen);
      pthread_setspecific(key,(void *)client_addr);
 }
```

for this type, still since client_addr may be changed between accept() and pthread_setspecific().

for the case where each thread has many tcp connections at the same time, it is even unimaginable!

so How can I get the client address for each thread?
Are there any work-around for this problem?
thanks!

Comment: The client address is a property of the socket - so when handing over the connected socket to the worker thread you already have all you need

Comment: seems cool, so how to get the clietn address from connfd?

Comment: As @NikolaiNFetissov answered, take a look at `getpeername()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call [`getpeername(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpeername.2.html) on the socket in the handling thread, no need to get all fancy with thread-local storage.